# Web Audio API: Stop all scheduled sounds from playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

So i have a bunch of loaded audio samples that I am calling the schedule function with in the code below:

```
let audio;

function playChannel() {
    let audioStart = context.currentTime;
    let next = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        scheduler(audioStart, next);
        next++;
    }
}
```

Here is the audio scheduler function:

```
function scheduler(audioStart, index) {
    audio = context.createBufferSource(); 
    audio.buffer = audioSamples[index];  //array with all the loaded audio
    audio.connect(context.destination);  
    audio.start(audioStart + (audio.buffer.duration * index));
}
```

And it's working fine and plays the scheduled sounds as it should.

How am I supposed to stop/cancel all the scheduled sounds from playing?

Because right now when I try to call the `stop()` method it will only stop the last scheduled sound from playing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of the BufferSource nodes you're creating inside scheduler, referenced by index, and then run through all of them.  E.g.:

```
var sources = [];

function scheduler(audioStart, index) {
    audio = context.createBufferSource();
    sources[index] = audio; 
    audio.buffer = audioSamples[index];  //array with all the loaded audio
    audio.connect(context.destination);  
    audio.start(audioStart + (audio.buffer.duration * index));
}

function stopAll() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (sources[i])
          sources[i].stop(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is correct, the `sources` array will keep growing indefinitely.

To fix that, you should listen to the source node's [`onended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/ended_event) and remove them from `sources` once they are done playing (or stopped).

Here's a class that encapsulates the logic to load a sound from a URL and play/stop it as many times as you want, keeping track of all currently playing sources and cleaning them up as needed:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const context = new AudioContext();

export class Sound {

    url = '';

    buffer = null;

    sources = [];

    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    load() {
        if (!this.url) return Promise.reject(new Error('Missing or invalid URL: ', this.url));

        if (this.buffer) return Promise.resolve(this.buffer);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open('GET', this.url, true);
            request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

            // Decode asynchronously:

            request.onload = () => {
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response, (buffer) => {
                    if (!buffer) {
                        console.log(`Sound decoding error: ${ this.url }`);

                        reject(new Error(`Sound decoding error: ${ this.url }`));

                        return;
                    }

                    this.buffer = buffer;

                    resolve(buffer);
                });
            };

            request.onerror = (err) => {
                console.log('Sound XMLHttpRequest error:', err);

                reject(err);
            };

            request.send();
        });
    }

    play(volume = 1, time = 0) {
        if (!this.buffer) return;

        // Create a new sound source and assign it the loaded sound's buffer:

        const source = context.createBufferSource();

        source.buffer = this.buffer;

        // Keep track of all sources created, and stop tracking them once they finish playing:

        const insertedAt = this.sources.push(source) - 1;

        source.onended = () => {
            source.stop(0);

            this.sources.splice(insertedAt, 1);
        };

        // Create a gain node with the desired volume:

        const gainNode = context.createGain();

        gainNode.gain.value = volume;

        // Connect nodes:

        source.connect(gainNode).connect(context.destination);

        // Start playing at the desired time:

        source.start(time);
    }

    stop() {
        // Stop any sources still playing:

        this.sources.forEach((source) => {
            source.stop(0);
        });

        this.sources = [];
    }

}
```

You can then do something like this:

```
const soundOne = new Sound('./sounds/sound-one.mp3')
const soundTwo = new Sound('./sounds/sound-two.mp3')

Promises.all([
  soundOne.load(),
  soundTwo.load(),
]).then(() => {
  buttonOne.onclick = () => soundOne.play();
  buttonTwo.onclick = () => soundOne.play();
})
```